# How to convert QTableWidget data to PDF using PyQt5 Python

Tags: python, pdf, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am working on a python project where I have data stored in `QTableWidget`. I have to export this data into `excel sheet` and `PDF`. I have been able to export data to `excel sheet` using below code. But unable to understand how can I convert it to `PDF`.

```
filename, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', '', ".xls(*.xls)")
wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = wbk.add_sheet("sheet", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
style = xlwt.XFStyle()
font = xlwt.Font()
font.bold = True
style.font = font
model = self.home_ui.reports_table.model()

for c in range(model.columnCount()):
    text = model.headerData(c, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
    first_col = sheet.col(c+1)
    l = len(text)
    first_col.width = (256 * l) + 1000
    sheet.write(0, c + 1, text, style=style)

for r in range(model.rowCount()):
    text = model.headerData(r, QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
    sheet.write(r + 1, 0, text, style=style)

for c in range(model.columnCount()):
    for r in range(model.rowCount()):
        text = model.data(model.index(r, c))
        sheet.write(r + 1, c + 1, text)

wbk.save(filename)
```

Above code is working fine and saving data to excel.

I have looked into other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50742457/print-qtablewidget-content-into-pdf) with same topic but all of them are in c++. I am looking for python equivalent.

Can anyone give me some good suggestion on how to convert data to `PDF`. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you review an answer you should not only see the code but the solution itself, that is, the logic that is in the background. In this particular case the solution is to create an HTML that shows the table content, and use QTextDocument with QPrinter to print the HTML to PDF.

Considering the above, it is not necessary to do the translation since it is enough to implement it from scratch since the logic is clear.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

w = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 10)
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("{}-{}".format(i, j))
        w.setItem(i, j, it)


filename = "table.pdf"
model = w.model()

printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.PrinterResolution)
printer.setOutputFormat(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
printer.setPaperSize(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.A4)
printer.setOrientation(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.Landscape)
printer.setOutputFileName(filename)

doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()

html = """<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>"""
html += "<table><thead>"
html += "<tr>"
for c in range(model.columnCount()):
    html += "<th>{}</th>".format(model.headerData(c, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal))

html += "</tr></thead>"
html += "<tbody>"
for r in range(model.rowCount()):
    html += "<tr>"
    for c in range(model.columnCount()):
        html += "<td>{}</td>".format(model.index(r, c).data() or "")
    html += "</tr>"
html += "</tbody></table>"
doc.setHtml(html)
doc.setPageSize(QtCore.QSizeF(printer.pageRect().size()))
doc.print_(printer)
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to understand your code as it include html and I am not familiar with html. Is it possible to draw borders around data to make them look like cells.?

Comment: @SAndrew 1) If you do not know a topic then you should investigate because if you want customization then the basics are not enough. 2) in my update I have already added simple borders.

Comment: I got it working `html = '''<table border="1" width="100%"><thead>'''`. Appologies just saw your comment

Comment: The subset of CSS accepted by pyqt continues to evolve. PyQt 5.9.2 does not accept the syntax "border: 1 px solid black". It will accept border-width, border-style, and border-color as separate properties. It will not recognize border-collapse or width properties in the table CSS.